# setChecked на изображении в галерее

Tags: android, изображения, checkbox, android-on-click

Есть активити с изображениями. При долгом нажатии на изображении появляется панель с кнопками и на каждом изображении появляется чекбокс. Далее уже можно нажимая на изображение отметить его флажком и или отправлять или удалять и тп. Хочется, чтобы изображение, на которое долго нажимаю отмечалось флажком сразу, но не выходит. Помогите разобраться!

```
public class GalleryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryItemAdapter.GalleryItemViewHolder> {

    private final String TAG =  GalleryItemAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int SELECTION_MODE_PICK = 0;
    public static final int SELECTION_MODE_SELECT = 1;

    public List<GalleryItem> getSelectedItems() {
        return mSelectedItems;
    }

    public void clearSelectedItems(){
        mSelectedItems.clear();
        if(mSelectionModeListener != null){
            mSelectionModeListener.onSelectionCountChanged(0);
        }
    }

    public void clearSelectedItems(){
        mSelectedItems.clear();
        if(mSelectionModeListener != null){
            mSelectionModeListener.onSelectionCountChanged(0);
        }
    }

    public interface ItemActionListener {
        void OnImageClick(GalleryItem item);
    }
    public interface SelectionModeListener {
        void onEnterSelectionMode();
        void onExitSelectionMode();
        void onSelectionCountChanged(int count);
    }
    private Context mContext;
    private List<GalleryItem> mItems;

    private ItemActionListener mListener;
    private SelectionModeListener mSelectionModeListener;

    private int mSelectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_PICK;
    private List<GalleryItem> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public GalleryItemAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public GalleryItemAdapter setData(List<GalleryItem> items) {
        mItems = items;
        return this;
    }
    public GalleryItemAdapter setActionListner(ItemActionListener listener){
        this.mListener = listener;
        return this;
    }
    public GalleryItemAdapter setSelectionModeListener(SelectionModeListener listener){
        this.mSelectionModeListener = listener;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public GalleryItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, viewGroup, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "creating new GalleryItemViewHolder for view " + view.toString());
        return new GalleryItemViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GalleryItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final GalleryItem item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.mImg.setOnLongClickListener(null);
        holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        if(item.getItemType() == GalleryItem.ITEM_HEADER){
            holder.mSectionTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
            holder.mSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // load image to view
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(mItems.get(position).getFile())
                    .resize(400, 400).centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.mImg);
            holder.mImg.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    if(mSelectionMode == SELECTION_MODE_SELECT){
                        Log.d(TAG, "selection mode: pick");
                        mSelectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_PICK;
                        if(mSelectionModeListener!=null){
                            mSelectionModeListener.onExitSelectionMode();
                        }
                        mSelectedItems.clear();
                    } else {
                        mSelectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_SELECT;
                        if (mSelectionModeListener != null) {
                            mSelectionModeListener.onEnterSelectionMode();
                        }
                    }
                    GalleryItemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            if(mSelectionMode == SELECTION_MODE_SELECT){
                holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setChecked(mSelectedItems.contains(item));
                holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                      holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setChecked(!holder.mSelectionCheckbox.isChecked());
                    }
                });
                holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged() for item id = " + item.getId());
                        if(isChecked){
                            mSelectedItems.add(item);
                        } else {
                            mSelectedItems.remove(item);
                        }
                        // notify subscriber on collection count changes
                        if(mSelectionModeListener != null){
                            mSelectionModeListener.onSelectionCountChanged(mSelectedItems.size());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // handle simple tap interractions
                holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(mListener != null) {
                            mListener.OnImageClick(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).getItemType();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
    public class GalleryItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mImg;
        private TextView mSectionTitle;
        private CheckBox mSelectionCheckbox;
        public GalleryItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mSectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_header);
            mImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            mSelectionCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_selector);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При долгом нажатии на изображении появляются флажки на каждом изображении, но они все неотмеченные. Нужно чтобы на том изображении на которое нажимал появлялся уже отмеченный флажок, а остальные добавлялись уже как обычно.

Comment: как я понимаю проблема в holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setChecked(mSelectedItems.contains(item));

Comment: В `onLongClick`, при условии что режим выбора активирован - нужно занести нажатый элемент в список выбранных.

Comment: woesss, а примерно не подскажете как в моем случае? Я уже бьюсь 2 дня над этой проблемой. Мозгов не хватает если честно это сделать, т.к. не программист, а переделываю методом тыка косяки "спеца".

Comment: Ну я, собственно, по вашему случаю и написал. Если прям конкретно: строку `mSelectedItems.add(item);` добавить в блок `else` в `onLongClick` в `onBindViewHolder`. Смотрите в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу же в `onLongClick`, при условии что режим выбора активирован - добавить нажатый элемент в список выбранных:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GalleryItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final GalleryItem item = mItems.get(position);
    holder.mImg.setOnLongClickListener(null);
    holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(null);
    holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    if(item.getItemType() == GalleryItem.ITEM_HEADER){
        holder.mSectionTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.mSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        // load image to view
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(mItems.get(position).getFile())
                .resize(400, 400).centerCrop()
                .into(holder.mImg);
        holder.mImg.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if(mSelectionMode == SELECTION_MODE_SELECT){
                    Log.d(TAG, "selection mode: pick");
                    mSelectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_PICK;
                    if(mSelectionModeListener!=null){
                        mSelectionModeListener.onExitSelectionMode();
                    }
                    mSelectedItems.clear();
                } else {
                    mSelectionMode = SELECTION_MODE_SELECT;
                    if (mSelectionModeListener != null) {
                        mSelectionModeListener.onEnterSelectionMode();
                    }
                    // заносим нажатый в список
                    mSelectedItems.add(item);
                    // дальше вызов notifyDataSetChanged() перерисует список
                    // уже с галочкой на этом элементе
                }
                GalleryItemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
        if(mSelectionMode == SELECTION_MODE_SELECT){
            holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setChecked(mSelectedItems.contains(item));
            holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setChecked(!holder.mSelectionCheckbox.isChecked());
                }
            });
            holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged() for item id = " + item.getId());
                    if(isChecked){
                        mSelectedItems.add(item);
                    } else {
                        mSelectedItems.remove(item);
                    }
                    // notify subscriber on collection count changes
                    if(mSelectionModeListener != null){
                        mSelectionModeListener.onSelectionCountChanged(mSelectedItems.size());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.mSelectionCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // handle simple tap interractions
            holder.mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(mListener != null) {
                        mListener.OnImageClick(item);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: woesss, спасибо! Все получилось, я такую же логику отрабатывал, но вставлял mSelectedItems.add(item) после строки mSelectionModeListener.onEnterSelectionMode() и выделялось все. Спасибо еще раз!